# Prefer swipe to delete over a competing swipe gesture

Tags: uitableview, ios9, uiswipegesturerecognizer, xlpagertabstrip

So I have a tableViewController inside a [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) view controller, basically a pod which allows me to swipe between child view controllers left and right. The problem is that I want to disable the view controller scroll when the user swipes on a cell on my tableView. In this case I want him to be able to see the delete option, instead of changing the viewController itself. Is this possible? Currently, I see the delete button only if I swipe really, really fast and in all other scenarios, the entire viewController is swiped away.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any sort of preference property for UIGestures. Instead, I believe the rule is the first gesture added takes precedent. However, in your specific circumstance with `XLPagerTabStrip`, you can simply disable scrolling in the interface builder for your `'containerView'` (subclass of `UIScrollView`). That solved the problem for me anyway, having my children view controllers' `UITableViews` actions appearing correctly.

Comment: But I want to use the scroll too, if it is done anywhere except the UITableViewCells :(

Comment: the views will scroll as normal! Just not the swipe gestures for the pager.

Comment: Try it out, and if it does not work as you expect it to, can you maybe edit your question and describe the problem a little different? I may not be understanding...